# C++ How to perform item assignment on a vector pointer?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

```
vector<string>* v1 = new vector<string>(10, "");
(*v1)[2] = "aaa";
```

Now I want to use the pointer v1 without dereferencing it, with the arrow operator:

```
v1->[2] = "aaa"; // DOES NOT COMPILE
```

What am I missing? Is it possible?

Comment: Do you come from Java or C#? In C++ there's no need to use `new` to create object, and in "modern" C++ there's seldom a need to use pointers outside of polymorphism.

Comment: And to answer your question, you can use e.g. `v1->operator[](2)`, which kind of defeats the purpose of operator overloading.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks! But that has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: You miss the point, that a new on a structure having the size of (lets say) 4*sizeof(void*) is mostly useless.

Comment: I'm just saying that I don't see the reason for using a pointer to a vector in this case. What is the use-case? What is the actual problem that you are trying to solve by using a pointer to a vector?

Comment: Vector will be huge and needs to go to heap

Comment: You do know that vectors allocate memory dynamically for the data it stores, so the elements in it will already be on the heap. You might want to read [a `std::vector` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)?

Comment: Sorry, it was more like a syntax question. If you put down an answer I'll accept it and case closed.

Comment: You might consider listening to the advice given to you by the experts above. You'll thank us for it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've discovered, overloaded operator syntax doesn't work with the arrow operator. But specifying the full method name does:

```
v1->operator[](2) = "aaa";
```

That said, the arrow operator *is* a dereferencing operator. These two lines are equivalent:

```
(*v1).foo()
v1->foo()
```

I don't see a particularly good reason to prefer one over the other.

In any case, operator[] isn't the only method that retrieves an array item from a vector. As pointed out in the comments, calling get() is nearly equivalent (it adds bounds checking but is otherwise identical).

Comment: If you want it to look a bit better, you can use `vi->at(2)`. The `at()` member function adds in bounds checking but is otherwise equivalent to `operator[]`